# Hypergeometric representation of Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, hypergeometric-functions, eisenstein-series

It is well known (Fricke ?) that $E_4^{1/4}$ and $E_6^{1/6}$ can be represented as Gauss hypergeometric functions of $1728/j$ and $1728/(1728-j)$ respectively.
The same result is true in levels $2$, $3$, and $4$ for instance, in which case
$E_4$, $E_6$, and $j$ must be replaced by analogous modular functions. The standard way of proving this is to show that both sides are solutions of the same linear differential equation of order $2$ with suitable additional conditions to ensure uniqueness. But this seems to involve in each case some ad hoc and not completely trivial computations. Is there a simple, more elegant manner to prove these results in a unified way without too much computation ?